# Cast a value with a other values type

Tags: python

Is it possible to cast a number behalf of a other number?
I tried this one, but type returns a string.

```
n = 1.34
i = 10
type(i)(n)
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit, then it will be easy for us to help.

Comment: Your example works.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? In Python, you generally shouldn't care what type the object is,

Comment: @SunilLulla I think OP wants to cast one variable based on another variable

Comment: `type(i)` shouldn't return a string

Comment: Thank it works, failure on my side. @MorganThrapp I need to cast for deep learning network parameters

Comment: Note that you aren't changing `n`.  `n` will still be a float.  `type(i)(n)` is the same as `int(n)`, which is to say that it calls an `int` constructor with `n` passed as a parameter

Comment: You can't "cast" anything in Python, really.  Python variables have no type whatsoever, so you'll never need to say anything like, "the variable `pet`, which was declared to be of type `Mammal`, is actually of type `Dog`... Trust me on this, compiler".  In Python, you can create a new object based on the value of some other object, but that's not at all like the "casting" done in C or Java.  It's closer to Java's [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) and similar factory methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, your example works fine:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5.0
>>> c = Decimal(5)
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(c)
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Cast b (float) as a's type (int):

```
>>> type(a)(b)
5
```

Cast a (int) as b type (float):

```
>>> type(b)(a)
5.0
```

Cast a (int) as c type (Decimal):

```
>>> type(c)(a)
Decimal('5')
```

Note that Python's duck-typing often makes this kind of casting unnecessary, though I can imagine some scenarios where it would be useful.